# How to detect when changes are made to the Windows Color and Appearance settings dialog?

Tags: winapi

I am trying to get my Application to detect when the Windows Themes change, and then be able to respond to that change.

To detect when themes change there is the handy `WM_THEMECHANGED` message which I am able to respond to.

What I would like is to also be able to determine when color settings change from here:

[image]

I have been searching and looking for any possible way to detect changes made from that dialog but I have yet to find any information for it.

So I would like to know whether it is possible or not to detect changes from the Window Color and Appearance dialog. I understand changes here are not the same as theme changes, but all the same I would like to be able to detect and respond to these changes as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WM_SYSCOLORCHANGE` message appears to respond to changes made to the System colors, which also includes changes made from the Window Color and Appearance dialog.

Answer (score 1):

When these settings are changed, `WM_SETTINGCHANGED` is broadcast to top-level windows with a `wParam` value of `SPI_SETNONCLIENTMETRICS` or `WM_SYSCOLORCHANGE` depending on which setting is changed.

Comment: `SPI_SETNONCLIENTMETRICS` is for changes to the height of the title bar. If you change colors, the message is `WM_SYSCOLORCHANGE`.